# Qual é a funcionalidade do método "heapify" do módulo heapq?

Tags: python-3.x, estrutura-de-dados, heap

Para que serve o método `heapify` da biblioteca **heapq** do Python? Como eu  poderia usá-lo em uma lista, por exemplo?

Comment: O `heapifiy` transforma a lista passada num heap. [Veja um exemplo de um heap na wikipedia por exemplo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap). Pelo que eu vi seria especificamente um *min-heap* mas só confirmando na documentação/código.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Heap

Antes de perceber para que serve o método `heapify` tem de perceber como funciona um *Heap*. Pela [documentação da *HeapQ*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) do Python vemos que a implementação usa um *Heap* Binário como *min-heap*.

Um *heap* desse gênero organiza-se como uma arvore binária, em que cada elemento pode ter um filho esquerdo e direito, e o menor elemento encontra-se no topo.

Ilustração deste princpio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A regra para um *min-heap* é que um elemento pai tem de ser menor ou igual a um elemento filho. Num *max-heap* esta regra é precisamente o oposto.

A figura anterior é apenas um representação visual do que um *heap* é, ele no entanto é disposto num array, com uma organização especifica. Os elementos são dispostos, olhando para a arvore, de cima para baixo e da esquerda para a direita.

Seguindo essa regra o *heap* assim ilustrado ficaria assim num array:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas a mesma relação existe neste array, embora que implícita:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para heaps com primeiro índice a `0` a formula para descobrir os filhos de um elemento é:

```
Filho Esquerda = 2 * i + 1
Filho Direita = 2 * i + 2
```

Em que `i` é a posição do elemento em questão.

Exemplificando para o elemento `17` que tem a posição `3`:

```
Filho Esquerda = 2 * 3 + 1 = 7 => posição 7 que corresponde ao valor 25
Filho Direita = 2 * 3 + 2 = 8 => posição 8 que corresponde ao valor 100
```

### Python

Passemos agora á utilização deste *heap* em python. Podemos começar por construir uma lista com os valores mostrados nas figuras anteriores:

```
lista = [100,3,2,17,19,36,1,25,7]
```

Agora ao chamarmos o método [`heapify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify) esta lista irá ser transformada num *heap* com todas as características vistas anteriormente:

```
import heapq #necessário importar heapq

lista = [100,3,2,17,19,36,1,25,7]

heapq.heapify(lista)
print(lista) #[1, 3, 2, 7, 19, 36, 100, 25, 17]
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/9Xmp8F)

Repare que a disposição em array não ficou exatamente igual ao ilustrado nas figuras anteriores, mas continua a ser um *heap* válido e equivalente.

Agora pode tirar partido do *heap* que tem e continuar a utilizar mais funções da biblioteca *heapq*. A titulo de exemplo podemos utilizar o [`heappop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop) que remove e devolve o primeiro elemento do *heap*. Sendo este um *min-heap* o elemento a remover é o mais pequeno:

```
menor = heapq.heappop(lista)
print(menor) #1
print(lista) #[2, 3, 17, 7, 19, 36, 100, 25]
```

[Veja este exemplo também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/wM3F7l)

### Motivação

É bem possível que neste momento se questione do porquê de utilizar uma estrutura de dados como um heap binário. Pois bem, esta estrutura de dados oferece-lhe complexidade diferentes para a maior parte das operações, sendo algumas mais rápidas que as de uma lista.

Complexidade de tempo com notação O para um *Heap* binário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto pode trazer-lhe vantagem dependendo do algoritmo que tem, e do seu objetivo.

Documentação para o [`heapify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify) e para o [`heappop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop)

Referencias:
[Heap na wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap)